# What is better - to transform my data before loading it to snowflake, or clone the loaded data to the desired table

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

For example, I have an 490,000 row array with the name, version, color and if it is available in a table. As it seems the largest size array is 120898752 via quora question: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-maximum-length-of-any-list-in-Python

Sample Data:

```
          name version      color  available
0       Bigtax   2.2.9     Indigo      False
1  Solarbreeze    7.00      Khaki      False
2  Toughjoyfax   0.7.1  Turquoise      False
3        Otcom    0.95     Indigo      False
4    Holdlamis    7.15  Turquoise      False
```

I want the final table to be the available colors and the app names for each color.

> gf = df.groupby(['name', 'color']).count()

```
                    version  available
name     color                        
Aerified Crimson          1          1
         Goldenrod        1          1
         Green            1          1
         Indigo           2          2
         Khaki            2          2
```

I read that it was recommended to upload data in 10mb pieces. Can I upload the large dataframe in one large sql query using the python connector already transformed each time I need to update it based on the original data? Or would transforming it in the Snowflake Table to a new table be a better plan?

My general usage for the year is planning on adding app versions and colors about 4 times a quarter.

Comment: Are you asking if it would be better to use Python or SQL to do your transformations? If so then I would leave the data in the Snowflake table and do the aggregations in SQL. Much easier that way.

Comment: Yes, in fact, I was wondering what is a good rule of thumb for size of transformations that are faster on Snowflake than then programmatically. I have not run into any limitations on aggregations with SQL or python yet.  Seems SQL may be easier and flexible.

Comment: go with SQL - Snowflake is built for these kinds of workloads (ELT) and SQL is more well known for these kind of workloads too

Comment: Where are you running your python code?